# How do I remove results from a first MySQL query, if they exist in a second MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

How do I remove results from the first query, if they exist in a second query?

I've looked over previous stackoverflow threads and still can't get it to work.

My `MySQL` queries so far are below:

```
SELECT roomL.CityCode, roomL.TableCode
FROM (SELECT roomL.CityCode, roomL.TableCode 
      FROM roomL
      WHERE roomL.StatusEnum = 1 
      AND roomL.TableCode NOT IN (select stock.TableCode from stock)
      AND roomL.TimeSeen BETWEEN 10/10/2014 AND Now())

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT roomL.CityCode , roomL.TableCode 
                  FROM roomL
                  WHERE roomL.StatusEnum = 1 
                  AND roomL.TableCode NOT IN (select stock.TableCode from stock)
                  AND roomL.TimeSeen BETWEEN DATE_ADD( 17/10/2014 ,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND Now())
```

Currently I'm getting the error:

**SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias**

Comment: Do you mind running through with me, how to make those changes via an example? Thanks

Comment: Yes they do, they each retrieve a set of results.

Comment: Fine,which is Primary key of roomL ?

Answer (score -1):

First alter the table with the proper datatype for timeseen, you'll need to add on extra column first:

```
ALTER table roomL
ADD COLUMN TimeSeen1 DATE;
```

Second update the new column from the strings im TimeSeen

```
UPDATE roomL
SET TimeSeen1 = STR_TO_DATE(TimeSeen, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Third remove the old column

```
ALTER TABLE roomL
DROP COLUMN TimeSeen;
```

Finally rename the new column (optional)

```
ALTER TABLE roomL
CHANGE COLUMN TimeSeen1 TimeSeen DATE;
```

Then you can use Strawberry's query with a little adjustment:

```
SELECT
     r.CityCode,
     r.TableCode
FROM
    roomL r
LEFT JOIN
    stock s
    ON r.TableCode = s.TableCode
WHERE
    r.Status_Enum = 1 AND
    r.TimeSeen BETWEEN '2014-10-10' AND '2014-10-18'
    AND s.TableCode IS NULL
```

Comment: After doing this, I still get the error 
SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You don't need subqueries, but if you use one in the FROM clause an alias is **required**

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
SELECT temp1.CityCode, temp1.TableCode
FROM (SELECT roomL.CityCode, roomL.TableCode 
      FROM roomL
      WHERE roomL.StatusEnum = 1 
      AND roomL.TableCode NOT IN (select stock.TableCode from stock)
      AND roomL.TimeSeen BETWEEN '2014-10-10' AND Now())temp1

left join (SELECT roomL.CityCode , roomL.TableCode 
                  FROM roomL
                  WHERE roomL.StatusEnum = 1 
                  AND roomL.TableCode NOT IN (select stock.TableCode from stock)
                  AND roomL.TimeSeen BETWEEN DATE_ADD( '2014-10-17' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND Now())temp2 
ON temp1.CityCode=temp2.CityCode AND temp1.TableCode=temp2.TableCode
WHERE temp2.CityCode IS NULL AND temp2.TableCode IS NULL;
```

Comment: Why do you use subqueries?

Comment: why i got - vote ..i dont know..my logic is correct....what is wrong in using sub querys..@Gervs

Comment: It's not logic to put something into a box and then put that box into another one. Also you use the **wrong** date format, and you have invalid use of NULL comparison (should be IS [NOT] NULL). Enough reason for a downvote

Comment: @Gervs..check it on mysql it is perfect syntax...it is working.

Comment: i made corrections to his code...i have not checked date format..i dont know about date format..but my approach is correct..

Comment: SQL dates are formatted in `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. If you use datetime functions on wrong formatted strings they will return NULL. If you make a comparison `NULL=NULL` it evaluates to NULL (not true or false), BUT the comparison `NULL IS NULL` evaluates to true. In short, you won't get a syntax error nor will you get the desired result. As for correct approach, compare both queries by putting them in an explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63475/discussion-between-karunakar-and-gervs).